# How do i style an image when it's inside the document.write function?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to style this cat image, but i can't seem to find out where to add the div class- it's probably really simple, but i am very new to javascript so hopefully someone can help me.

```
document.write('<img src="bilder/cat2.jpg">');
```

Comment: Consider not using `document.write`. Instead consider using `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild`?

Comment: I can try that- just wondering, are u sure there is no way to do it with just document.write? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways, oneliner and CSS:

```
[JS] document.write('<img style="margin: 10px; border: 1px solid #FFF;" src="bilder/cat2.jpg">');
```

---

```
[JS] document.write('<img class="myclassforthisimage" src="bilder/cat2.jpg">');
[CSS] .myclassforthisimage { margin: 10px; border: 1px solid #FFF; }
```